# How can I get IP addresses of Azure web app instances

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have my web app running on Azure with scale out to have multiple instances. 
I can get the list instances name using the Management API of Azure as below

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"SubscriptionID"/resourceGroups/"ResournceGroupName"/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/"sitename"/instances?api-version=2018-02-01
```

This API provides me the below information

```
"value": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/websitename/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/websitename/instances/instancename",
      "name": "68e9f48782245c3a112318 INSTANCE NAME ac97aa9f0b55a4b0eb7a0",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/instances",
      "location": "UK West",
      "properties": {
        "name": "68e9f48782245c3a112318 INSTANCE NAME ac97aa9f0b55a4b0eb7a0",
        "siteInstanceName": "68e9f48782245c3a112318 INSTANCE NAME ac97aa9f0b55a4b0eb7a0"
      }
```

I wanted to know the IP address of each instance. Can any one please help me how can i get that.

Comment: Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> You can't know beforehand which IP address a given app instance will
>   use to make the outbound connection

So, unfortunately, you just can know the possible outbound IP addresses and not the exact IP address. The inbound IP address may also change when you perform some actions. But you can get a static inbound IP address if you configure an IP-based SSL binding. See [Get static inbound IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-static-inbound-ip).

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the possible IP list of the scaled instances in Azure Portal. Find the possibilities of retrieving the IP of scaled instances [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change).

Comment: This is the probable list of IPs. Can I get the actual IP for instances running at that time.